# mpeg-dash toolkit, how can I make such videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, mpeg-dash

I was reading about this nice specification but I'm not sure what's the current status. Ffmpeg has some coverage

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#webm_005fdash_005fmanifest

but it is not clear to me if I could encode videos in such format. 
So, the question is, If I were to produce mpeg-dash compliant videos, how would I do nowadays? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **MP4Box** which supports MPEG-DASH

> MP4Box can be used to generate content conformant to the MPEG-DASH specification, aka ISO/IEC 23009-1 available in ISO Publicly Available Standards.

DASH Support in MP4Box:

http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/dash/

DASH Streaming Support:

http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/2012/02/01/dash-support/

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a step-by-step toturial on how to generate MPEG-DASH content using x264 and MP4Box: 
http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2014/11/mpeg-dash-content-generation-using-mp4box-and-x264/

Alternatively, you can use a cloud-based transcoding service like http://www.bitcodin.com, also here you can find a step-by-step tutorial: http://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/02/create-mpeg-dash-hls-content-for-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness you might as well use the dash.encrypt tool.Even though it states 'encrypt' it can as well create plain and unecrypted DASH streams. There is a step by step example as well:

https://github.com/castlabs/dashencrypt/wiki